# Leukemia this merciless desease

Tags: cancer

My little sister is getting chemotherapy recently as we found that she is suffering from acute lymphatic leukemia.

1. Is this desease can be treated, and will she be okay, or it is a fatal one?
2. I am studying medicine but I am still in second year medical school so I want to know more about leukemia to be able to help her. What should I do? Is there any course online that can help me?
3. Some types of chemotherapy is not available here (as L-asparaginase & purinezole), so can anyone help us and sent this medicine for us when we need them? They are available nowadays, but I am talking about later.

Comment: ALL is very survivable and the majority do survive, but specific questions about her case need to be directed to her doctor. Nobody here can send you drugs. If you're in medical school then your school has a library that you should already know how to use, so I would suggest starting there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the final question is off-topic and the second one is opinion-based. The first one, though is trivial: If your sister is getting chemotherapy, then clearly she is being treated.

Comment: @HDE226868 Furthermore, these are multiple questions in one post that, apart from having all to do with leukaemia, are too broad to be answered in one post.

Comment: In the United States the childhood survival rate is reportedly about 85%. Untreated the disease is fatal within 60 days. Supportive care is more important than chemotherapy. Supportive care means preventing secondary infections and controlling fever.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to hear about your little sister. You may well have found an answer to these questions by now, but I have an answer below for the sake of others who may have similar questions. I assume you are asking about Acute Lymphoblastic Leukaemia or "ALL".

The American National Cancer Institute has very comprehensive and well presented material online. This is for health professionals [ https://www.cancer.gov/types/leukemia/hp/child-all-treatment-pdq ] and also information which is for patients / parents [ https://www.cancer.gov/types/leukemia/patient/child-all-treatment-pdq ].

Significant advances in ALL treatment and prognosis have been made in recent years:
" For ALL, the 5-year survival rate has increased over the same time from 60% to approximately 90% for children younger than 15 years and from 28% to more than 75% for adolescents aged 15 to 19 years." 
**Ref:** Howlader N, Noone AM, Krapcho M: SEER Cancer Statistics Review (CSR) 1975-2013. Bethesda, Md: National Cancer Institute, 2015.

This applies to the US & UK population (intensive chemotherapy with excellent supportive care, which is costly), but as I'm not sure where you are based I cannot answer about the prognosis in your area.

I'm afraid I cannot answer your third question about supplying chemotherapy.